# SQL Server connection breaking

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing some issue while running a batch that pulls data from SQL Server to mysql. I am pulling data in chunks in the beginning for 5-6 lots (1 lots = 5000 rows). It works fine but after sometimes it stops suddenly without any exception/errors and I get an error

> The connection is broken and recovery is not possible. The connection is marked by the client driver as unrecoverable. No attempt was made to restore the connection

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How good is the connection between the two PCs?

Comment: If you are pulling data from SQL Server, seems you have more of a MySQL issue - which you did not tag. But much depends on how exactly you have set this up - and perhaps which versions / editions of the various bits of software that are involved.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to re-start the failed job assuming that there won't any data duplicates issue. If that doesn't help then make sure that the connection between the MySQL and SQL Server is fine or not. As far as I know, the error message is stating that it is related connection failure. Contact your admin to test whether the required connections are fine or not.

Comment: I have tried to create the connection but that doesn't help. i can't restart my whole batch process as its a long run...... it takes around 40 minutes to complete as i am loading alot of data and data needs to be run in sequence as it is dependent to the previous one.

Comment: If you are sure that the data is connection is fine, then take a back up of the data from your table and then restart the job. There will be an option called Start Job at or restart from. Then the job will resume from that step onwards. If you are newbie who is loading data using this job then contact your team members before proceeding on with this. Your job is more of an internal process and that should be handled based on how your job is designed. There is no generalized answer for your question. Reach out to your project team.